# What does ^= do in python

Tags: python, arrays

I have seen the operator ^= in code now once and I dont know what it does. This was used to find a single occurrence of a number in an array. So A = [1,1,2,3,3] it should return 2.  This is how it was used

```
def solution(A):
    lone_num = 0
    for number in A:
        lone_num ^= number
    return lone_num
```

Not particularly sure what it does.

Comment: I know `^` works as a __XOR__ or to the power operator, but have never come across `^=`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`^` is the [binary XOR operator](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/operators/bitwise_XOR.html). In short, it converts input into binary numbers and performs a bitwise [XOR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_gate) operation.

```py
>>> 2^3 # 10 XOR 11
1 # 01
```

The expression `lone num ^= number` is equivalent to

```py
lone_num = lone_num ^ number
```

I'd be happy to answer any additional questions you might have.

Comment: @chepner I just realized that after posting my answer. I made an edit to make my answer more pertinent and concise.

Comment: Just so I get this right so lone starts at 0 then goes to 1. It sees another 1 in the array and says its fine. It sees a 2 and then goes to 2 this I get. But when the loop reaches 3 how does it stay 2?